# License - assignment date

Tags: soql, licenses, userlicense

Every few months we analyze how many of our users have a Salesforce license assigned and the utilization. Is there a SOQL query that will tell me the date the Salesforce license was assigned to the user.

Comment: Highly recommend using Reports and/or Dashboards to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaOsoGKDbxY

Comment: Hello @identigral. I watched that video prior to posting my question. Unfortunately it does not answer my question regarding seeing the date the Salesforce license was assigned to the user which is what I am looking for.

Comment: The linked question above does answer it - it's `CreatedDate` on `User` object because you can't create a user without a license. If you reassign licenses, then setup audit trail.

Comment: Hello. Yes. I did see that as well prior to posting this. In my case I want to capture both on create and reassignment. The issue with doing this via the setup audit trail is that there is a limit of only being able to capture the information going back 6 months.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing out of the box that will help you with the reassignment. The workaround for 6 months limit involves building a process where you periodically copy the records from Setup Audit Trail to your own custom object. Flow is a good no-code approach to implementing this: https://unofficialsf.com/lightning-flow-tutorials or

Comment: Okay thank you. I was hoping a SOQL report would be a good approach.